# Task not serializable error in Spark - Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to read a file inside a worker node as follows but it is giving an error saying that **Task not serializable**. My code is as follows:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd1 = pairs.reduceByKey(new Function2<String, String, String>() {
@Override
public String call(String v1, String v2) throws Exception {
    JavaRDD <String> br = sc.textFile("C:\\myFile.txt");
    return v1+v2;
    }
});
```

How can I get rid of this error? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you trying to achieve with this code? you shouldn't call `sc.textFile` from these things

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to read the file on the worker nodes and using the spark framework you don't need to do anything. You just need to write the code of reading the text file and spark would read it on executors in form of RDD. If you are doing collect operation then everything comes on the driver node.

For example in scala you can do below:

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("C:\\myFile.txt")
```

The above line of code will return you RDD(Resilient Distributed DataSet)

If you need any specific number of partitions for your use case you can use below code where we can provide the value for the argument which is optional.

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("C:\\myFile.txt",5)
```